# Xamarin cannot scroll textview

Tags: android, xamarin

I am trying to scroll Xamarin (android) textview content.However, so far that did not work how I expected. I tried wrapping textview in scrollview but that did not work either. For some reason textview with @+id/ttext pushes other elements as I add more lines.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mainBack"
    android:background="@drawable/lightblue"
    android:weightSum="3">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center">
        <Button
            android:text="Start Recording"
            android:textSize="13dp"
            android:layout_width="110.0dp"
            android:layout_height="64.0dp"
            android:id="@+id/btnRecord"
            android:width="150dp"
            android:height="120dp"
            android:shadowColor="#ffababab"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0.0dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0.0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0.0dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0.0dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:text="MyNote:"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="82.0dp"
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />
         <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/ttext"
            android:textColor="#ffedf01d"
            android:maxLines = "10"
            android:scrollbars = "vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: When you say "I am trying to scroll Xamarin (android) textview" you mean you are trying to scroll the content of the TextView?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to scroll the content of the textview

Comment: what do you expect it to do if you specified android:maxLines = "10" and android:layout_height="match_parent"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your XML I can see your issue is because for your **ttext** **TextView** the layout_height is set as "match_parent". Change this to "wrap_content" and the TextView will only grow up as much as the maxLines, in your case it will grow up to the size of 10 lines.